# NHibernate and weird casting exception

Tags: wpf, data-binding, nhibernate

I'm fighting it the second day and I'm just fed up.

I'm getting weird exceptions connected with my UI.

First things first.
My model looks basically like that:

Base class:

```
public class DbItem: ObservableModel
{
    public virtual Document ParentDocument { get; set; }

    Guid id;
    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    string name = string.Empty;
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Next we have PeriodBase class:

```
public enum PeriodType
{
    Year,
    Sheet
}

public abstract class PeriodBase : DbItem
{
    public virtual Period ParentPeriod { get; set; }
    public virtual PeriodType PeriodType { get; set; }
}
```

There are some more properties, but I just deleted them here for clarity.

Next, we have Period class that inherits from PeriodBase:

```
public class Period : PeriodBase
{
    IList<PeriodBase> periods = new ObservableCollection<PeriodBase>();
    public virtual IList<PeriodBase> Periods
    {
        get { return periods; }
        set
        {
            if (periods != value)
            {
                periods = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Period can have other periods and Sheets (which also inherites from PeriodBase):

```
public class Sheet : PeriodBase
{
    DateTimeOffset startDate;
    public override DateTimeOffset StartDate
    {
        get { return startDate; }
        set
        {
            if (startDate != value)
            {
                startDate = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    DateTimeOffset endDate;
    public override DateTimeOffset EndDate
    {
        get { return endDate; }
        set
        {
            if (endDate != value)
            {
                endDate = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally we have document class, that is made up of Periods:

```
public class Document: DbItem
{
    IList<Period> periods = new ObservableCollection<Period>();
    public virtual IList<Period> Periods
    {
        get { return periods; }
        set
        {
            if (periods != value)
            {
                periods = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you may guess, I get a tree hierarchy like that:

```
- Document
  - Period 1
    - Sheet 1
```

My bindings look like this:

```
public class DocumentMap : DbItemMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Table("documents");
        HasMany(x => x.Periods).ForeignKeyConstraintName("ParentDocument_id");
    }
}


public class PeriodBaseMap: DbItemMap<PeriodBase>
{
    public PeriodBaseMap()
    {
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
        References(x => x.ParentPeriod);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PeriodType).CustomType<PeriodType>();
    }
}

public class PeriodMap : SubclassMap<Period>
{
    public PeriodMap()
    {
        Table("periods");
        Abstract();
        References(x => x.ParentDocument);
        HasMany(x => x.Periods).Inverse().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class SheetMap : SubclassMap<Sheet>
{
    public SheetMap()
    {
        Table("sheets");
        Abstract();
        Map(x => x.StartDate);
        Map(x => x.EndDate);
    }
}
```

For now, I just do eager loading everywhere. Just for simplicity.

Now WPF. This is how I create my TreeView (I'm using syncfusion controls):

```
<sf:TreeViewAdv>
    <sf:TreeViewItemAdv  
            Header="Document" 
            LeftImageSource="../Resources/database.png" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}" 
            IsExpanded="True"
            >
        <sf:TreeViewItemAdv.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Periods}"> <!-- Period -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> <!-- Sheet -->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </sf:TreeViewItemAdv.ItemTemplate>
    </sf:TreeViewItemAdv>
</sf:TreeViewAdv>
```

And everything works until I save the records. It's just simple SaveAsync's in one transaction.

Everything gets saved but then I get a weird error. Application crashes with message: Cannot cast TreeViewItemAdv to PeriodBase.

What the heck? I can't even find the place when it's really throws.
This is stacktrace from exception info:

```
in NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.System.Collections.IList.IndexOf(Object value)
in System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.InternalIndexOf(Object item)
in Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls.TreeViewItemAdv.Initialize(FrameworkTemplate template)
in Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls.TreeViewItemAdv.TreeViewItemAdv_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
in System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
in System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
in System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
in System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
in MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
in System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
in System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

What's important, I get the same error after I start the application and load the document and click on the expander in treeview to expand Period. But everything works fine when I run the app for the first time, until I save the document.

What can be the problem?

**In reply to Mark Feldman's post**

I decided to reply in an answer as this is too long to comment. This is my first meeting with ORM, so I may have some wrong thoughts about this. I have just one model in my solution. Normally (using SQL) it would work. I would take an object, INSERT it into DB, and the other way also.

So I did the same way here. I just have one business model which has some simple business rules. It is used in ViewModels, and it's stored in db. Is it bad solution? Should I have another model and somewhat break DRY principle?

In my head it was suppose to work like this: User clicks "Create new Sheet". Here you are (this is part of my ViewModel -> method that is called from command):

```
void CreateNewSheetInActiveDocument()
{
    Sheet sh = ActiveDocument.CreateItem<Sheet>();
    ActiveDocument.LastPeriod.Periods.Add(sh);
}
```

This is more like pseudocode but it keeps the idea. Active document creates my sheet. This is done so because document signs to PropertyChanged event just to know if it was modified. Periods is ObservableCollection, so that I can react to adding and removing elements. Thanks to that period can set parentPeriod for my sheet automatically.

And then user saves it to db:

```
async Task SaveDocument(Document doc)
{
    foreach(var item in doc.ModifiedItems)
      db.SaveOrUpdate(item);
}
```

ModifiedItems is simply just a dictionary that keeps items that were modified. Thanks to this I don't have to save the whole document, just modified items.

So as far as I understand you this is not the way it should be. So what would be the PROPER way to do that? Or maybe ORM is not suitable here?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there have been major changes to NHibernate in the years since I've used it you can't just derive your model classes from ObservableModel and expect it to work. It appears that your reasoning for this is to give INPC to your DB models, which some would argue isn't good separation of concerns and suggests that your view model layer hasn't been designed properly.

That said, if you really are adamant about doing it then instead of deriving your entities from ObservableModel try using something like Castle Dynamic Proxy to inject INPC into your entities when NHibernate first creates them. Ayende Rahien's post [NHibernate & INotifyPropertyChanged](https://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged) shows how to do this and also provides the code you'll need.

The next problem you'll face is the issue of collections. Again, you can't just assign an `ObservableCollection<T>` to an `IList<T>` property and expect it to work, NHibernate replaces the entire list when it deserializes collections back in rather than using add/remove on an existing collection that you've already assigned. It's possible to replace the list with an `ObserveableCollection<T>` after its been loaded, but if you do that then NHibernate will think the entire list has changed, irrespective of whether it has or not, and serialize the whole thing back out again. You'll get away with it at first, but pretty soon the performance hit is going to start to hurt.

To work around that problem you're going to have to use a convention so that NHibernate creates collection entities that support INotifyCollectionChanged. Unfortunately the page where I originally read about this has long since disappeared, so I'll have to just post the code here (regrettably without attribution). I've only used conventions with NHibernate Fluent, so I'll leave you to find out how to apply them in your own case, but here's what you need...

```
public class ObservableBagConvention : ICollectionConvention
{
    public void Apply(ICollectionInstance instance)
    {
        Type collectionType = typeof(ObservableBagType<>)
            .MakeGenericType(instance.ChildType);
        instance.CollectionType(collectionType);
        instance.LazyLoad();            
    }
}

public class ObservableBagType<T> : CollectionType, IUserCollectionType
{
    public ObservableBagType(string role, string foreignKeyPropertyName, bool isEmbeddedInXML)
        : base(role, foreignKeyPropertyName, isEmbeddedInXML)
    {
    }

    public ObservableBagType()
        : base(string.Empty, string.Empty, false)
    {

    }
    public IPersistentCollection Instantiate(ISessionImplementor session, ICollectionPersister persister)
    {
        return new PersistentObservableGenericBag<T>(session);
    }

    public override IPersistentCollection Instantiate(ISessionImplementor session, ICollectionPersister persister, object key)
    {
        return new PersistentObservableGenericBag<T>(session);
    }

    public override IPersistentCollection Wrap(ISessionImplementor session, object collection)
    {
        return new PersistentObservableGenericBag<T>(session, (ICollection<T>)collection);
    }

    public IEnumerable GetElements(object collection)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)collection);
    }

    public bool Contains(object collection, object entity)
    {
        return ((ICollection<T>)collection).Contains((T)entity);
    }

    protected override void Clear(object collection)
    {
        ((IList)collection).Clear();
    }

    public object ReplaceElements(object original, object target, ICollectionPersister persister, object owner, IDictionary copyCache, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        var result = (ICollection<T>)target;
        result.Clear();
        foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable)original))
        {
            if (copyCache.Contains(item))
                result.Add((T)copyCache[item]);
            else
                result.Add((T)item);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override object Instantiate(int anticipatedSize)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    public override Type ReturnedClass
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(PersistentObservableGenericBag<T>);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code for the convention, you use it with this collection class:

```
public class PersistentObservableGenericBag<T> : PersistentGenericBag<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged,
                                                 INotifyPropertyChanged, IList<T>
{
    private NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler _collectionChanged;
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;

    public PersistentObservableGenericBag(ISessionImplementor sessionImplementor)
        : base(sessionImplementor)
    {
    }

    public PersistentObservableGenericBag(ISessionImplementor sessionImplementor, ICollection<T> coll)
        : base(sessionImplementor, coll)
    {
        CaptureEventHandlers(coll);
    }

    public PersistentObservableGenericBag()
    {
    }

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add
        {
            Initialize(false);
            _collectionChanged += value;
        }
        remove { _collectionChanged -= value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            Initialize(false);
            _propertyChanged += value;
        }
        remove { _propertyChanged += value; }
    }

    #endregion

    public override void BeforeInitialize(ICollectionPersister persister, int anticipatedSize)
    {
        base.BeforeInitialize(persister, anticipatedSize);
        CaptureEventHandlers(InternalBag);
    }

    private void CaptureEventHandlers(ICollection<T> coll)
    {
        var notificableCollection = coll as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var propertyNotificableColl = coll as INotifyPropertyChanged;

        if (notificableCollection != null)
            notificableCollection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

        if (propertyNotificableColl != null)
            propertyNotificableColl.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler changed = _propertyChanged;
        if (changed != null) changed(this, e);
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler changed = _collectionChanged;
        if (changed != null) changed(this, e);
    }
}
```

And that's it! Now NHibernate will deserialize your collections as type `PersistentObservableGenericBag<T>`.

So that's how you inject INPC into entities at runtime, but there are a couple of ways to accomplish what you need without actually having to do that. Apart from being easier to implement they also don't require the use of reflection, which is a factor if you ever need to migrate your code to something that doesn't allow it (e.g. Xamarin.iOS). Adding basic INPC can be achieved by simply adding [ProprtyChanged.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/) which will add it to your class properties IL automatically at build time. For change collection you're better off keeping your collections as type `IList<T>`, representing them with classes of type `ObserveableCollection<T>` in your view models and then just writing a bit of code, or a helper function, to keep the two synchronized.

UPDATE: I managed to track down the original project where I got that code, it's part of [Fabio Maulo's uNhAddIns project](https://bitbucket.org/fabiomaulo/unhaddins/src/22f46eed957110ec754968a2edfbefe91bfb0f3a/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns.WPF/Collections/?at=default).

Answer (score 0):

After Mark Feldman's changes, the error still occures. But when I changed the tree control to standard one, the problem went away. That means there is an error in Syncfusion control. I have reported it.